# how to convert Map<Integer, List<String>> to Map<Integer, Set<String>>

Tags: java

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapList = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> mapSet = new TreeMap<>();
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entriesSortedByValues(mapList)) {
            set.addAll(entry.getValue());
            mapSet.put(entry.getKey(), set);
        }
```

It doesnt  work. I want to copy mapList to mapSet.

Comment: You have to create a new set for each iteration, not one set for all iterations. If you would have debugged your code, you would have seen that you keep constantly writing to the same set.

Answer (score 4):

You keep adding and modifying the same object for all the keys.

What you currently do can be viewed as this:

[image]

So to fix that, create a new Set at each iteration of the loop.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapList = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> mapSet = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entriesSortedByValues(mapList)) {
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.addAll(entry.getValue());
    mapSet.put(entry.getKey(), set);
}
```

Also you could use the constructor that takes a collection as parameter.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapList = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> mapSet = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entriesSortedByValues(mapList)) {
    mapSet.put(entry.getKey(), new TreeSet<>(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a List to Set using `HashSet`'s constructor like, `new HashSet<String>(myList);`

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapList = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> mapSet = new TreeMap<>();

   for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entriesSortedByValues(mapList)) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(entry.getValue());
        mapSet.put(entry.getKey(), set);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Set in your for loop

```
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entriesSortedByValues(mapList)) {
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.addAll(entry.getValue());
        mapSet.put(entry.getKey(), set);
    }
```